# Adding the bootstrap theme to one region

Tags: theming

I have complex site with a custom theme.  I was thinking of implementing the Bootstrap theme, but only for one region.

Is this possible?  Is there a different way to go about this?

thanks so much : )

Comment: Are you just want to theme and right html for that specific region?